# How to setup a CICD pipeline for Eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, maven, gitlab, eclipse-plugin, cicd

I am working on developing a set of plugins to implement a new DSL with ECore, Xtext and Xtend.

So long, I can manually export the plugins (`File → Export → Plug-in Development → Deployable plug-ins and fragments`) then users copy them in the plugin folder of their target Eclipse (that should embed the necessary dependencies of the plugins!!)

What I would like to do is to :

1- "install" the plugins in a more smart way where, the necessary dependencies are automatically installed if missing in the target Eclipse.

2- set up a CICD pipeline in Gitlab to automatically build the plugins at each commit.

3- Set up in the CICD pipeline a build of a new Eclipse  that users can simply download with the plugins and the corresponding dependencies (could be from a pre configured Eclipse)

Do you know of any documentation to do so?

Tks in advance.

Comment: Maven Tycho is the common way to do this. See [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html).

Comment: Note: you never just copy plug-ins to the plugins folder, that doesn't work.

Comment: please check the new Xtext project wizard, you can select to create a feature + update site there + maven as build system which will create a tycho based build